# Laravel pagination latest throwing non object error

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I'm trying to execute a query, which works fine.

```
$thoughts = Thought::with('user')->paginate(10);
```

When I try to order the data I get trying to find a property of non-object error.

```
$thoughts = Thought::with('user')->latest()->paginate(10);
```

The non object points to this line

```
<td>{{ $thought->user->username}} <span>ID - {{ $thought->user_id}}</span></td>
```

Comment: Both those queries work fine for my local `User` model. `latest()` defaults to `orderBy($column, "desc");` where `$column` is `created_at`, but even if you use the wrong column, it doesn't throw a "trying to find a property of non-object" error, but rather a "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column" error. Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Following your edit, it is likely that `$thought->user` is `null`. Might want to add a check for something like `{{ $thought->user ? $thought->user->username : "No User" }}`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks @TimLewis